# Use string as a JSON command

Tags: json

I have this string:

```
var test = "toAdd";
```

I want to use it to extract data from JSON, like:

```
console.log(value.stats.test);
```

As you see, `test` is not correct, as it is just a string and can't be used, it is just not recognized at all. How do I make it recognize?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are attempting to do is this:

```
var someVar;
someVar.test = 'Sample';
someVar.test.attribute = 'Another sample';

// this:
console.log(someVar['test']['attribute']);

// will produce the same as this:
console.log(someVar['test'].attribute);

// as well as the same as this:
console.log(someVar.test['attribute']);
```

This will print "Another sample".

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with JSON. This is just javascript, and like anything where the `.` notation won't work switch to array notation:

```
foo.bar.baz = 'qux';
alert(foo['bar'].baz); // popup with 'qux'
         ^-----^-- note these
```

In your case, `value.stats[test]`. Now "test" isn't an array key, it's a variable whose value gets used as the key.

Comment: @Ariel, want to get use it in a loop. This is just a sample.